# How to provide a subjectAltName when generating a Certificate Request in IIS?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, subject-alternative-names

It seems the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Vivaldi no longer work with our Domain Certificates generated by Active Directory Certificate Services because they lack a subjectAltName.  My question is how would one go about generating a "Request Certificate" that contains the subjectAltName?  I'd prefer to use an IIS wizard.

Comment: certreq can do this

Comment: IIS console doesn't provide such functionality. You have to use MMC or certreq.exe tool.

Comment: With very little work these comments could be answers...